# ListView with a Navigator as child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to place a `Navigator` as child of a `ListView` widget. I'm doing this in order to have some static top content (i.e. a top navbar with a navigation options) and below that, some dynamic content based on the routing of the `Navigator`. I want to use a `ListView` instead of a `Column` in order to be able to scroll all the content, including the top navigation bar.

However, I'm getting a render exception, as the content of the `Navigator` widget is not bounded, and therefore can not be places inside a `ListView`, as it doesn't have any size constraints.

Is there any workaround in order to achieve such an effect?

```
|------------------| ^
| STATIC NAVBAR    | | SCROLL
|------------------| |
|                  | ^
|    NAVIGATOR     |
|     CONTENT      |
|                  |
|------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

First off a `SingleChildScrollView` would *probably* suit your needs better to scroll a single widget.

To solve your render exception you should put you `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView` as a *child* of `Navigator` as your intended effect is to scroll the contents of each routed widget. This isn't the only way to do it, I just think it would be easier for you to manage constraints for each child route. Either way, you're going to need to bound the children of your `Navigator` at some point in the vertical direction.

Comment: Thanks for aswerings! I don't think `SingleChildScrollView` will do the trick, as it can only have one child. However, I need to be able to scroll both the navigator content AND the static top navigation menu. I've included an example in my question for clarification.

Comment: @pitazzo You can have Scaffold with an app bar as a child of Navigator and SingleChildScrollView as the body of the Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabBar so you can achieve the navigation that you meant in your question. You can put the `TabBar` inside the `bottom` property of `Scaffold - AppBar()`.

For documentation you can check this official documentation of how to work with tabs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs)

Example of my work :

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: AppBarTitle(),
    bottom: TabBar(
      controller: _tabController, // define your TabController
      tabs: _tabs, //list of tab widgets
    ),
  ),
  body: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: <Widget>[
      // Here you can put your ListView widget as your dynamic contents
    ],
  ),
);
```